# Generic Encodable could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an API class with the following function:

```
static func JSONPostRequest<EncodableType:Codable, DecodableType:Codable>(endpoint: String, jsonData: EncodableType, callback: @escaping (DecodableType) -> Void, clientErrorCallback: @escaping (Error) -> Void, responseErrorCallback: @escaping (URLResponse) -> Void, requestHeaders: [String: String]?) {

    // Encoding the data into JSON
    var jsonData: Data = Data();
    do {
        jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(jsonData)
    }
    catch {
        print("JSON Encode")
        return ;
    }

    // Setup the request
    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.endpoint + self.apiVersion + "/" + endpoint)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    // Set the custom headers
    if(requestHeaders != nil) {
        for (headerKey, headerValue) in requestHeaders! {
            request.setValue(headerValue, forHTTPHeaderField: headerKey)
        }
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        // Was there an error in request?
        if error != nil {
            clientErrorCallback(error!)
            return
        }

        // Response code is 2XX?
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            responseErrorCallback(response!)
            return
        }

        // Has mime type fine?
        guard let mime = response!.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
            print("Wrong MIME type!")
            return
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let loginResponse = try! decoder.decode(DecodableType.self, from: data!)

        callback(loginResponse)
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

But when I would like to call it from my login view ... :

```
API.JSONPostRequest(
        endpoint: "login",
        jsonData: LoginRequest(username: self.username, password: self.password),
        callback: { loginResponse in
            // success callback

            if loginResponse.success && loginResponse.token != "" {
                callback(loginResponse)
            }
            else {
                // backend logic error
            }
        }, clientErrorCallback: { error in
            // client error
        }, responseErrorCallback: { urlResponse in
            // response error
        }, requestHeaders: headers
    )
```

... I get the following error message:

```
Generic parameter 'EncodableType' could not be inferred
```

Here's my LoginRequest implementation:

```
struct LoginRequest: Codable {
var username: String;
var password: String;
```

}

The error message shows near the first line of the function call, near "API.JSONPostRequest(".

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a type for `loginResponse`, and there's no way from this code to guess what it is. Looking at the code you've posted, I can't figure out what the response is supposed to be (nothing you've posted here has a `.success` or `.token` value).

I assume you meant to add the following code:

```
struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    var success: Bool
    var token: String
}
```

And I assume somewhere there is a variable `callback` of type `(LoginResponse) -> Void`.

With that type, you'll still need to let the compiler know it's what you expect. It has no way to guess of the infinite number of types this could return, that you want `LoginResponse`:

```
        ...
        callback: { (loginResponse: LoginResponse) in
        ...
```

Alternately, you can adjust your type signature to pass the expected type, for example:

```
static func JSONPostRequest<Request, Response>(endpoint: String,
                                               jsonData: Request,
                                               returning: Response.Type = Response.self,
                                               callback: @escaping (Response) -> Void,
                                               clientErrorCallback: @escaping (Error) -> Void,
                                               responseErrorCallback: @escaping (URLResponse) -> Void,
                                               requestHeaders: [String: String]?)
    where Request: Encodable, Response: Decodable {
```

This would allow you to pass `returning: LoginResponse.self`, which can be nicer than embedding it in the closure:

```
        ...
        returning: LoginResponse.self,
        callback: { loginResponse in
        ...
```

(That said, what I'm discussing here fixes the fact that `DecodableType` is actually ambiguous. The fact that you're getting an error on `EncodableType` suggests that you have other type-mismatches. I recommend simplifying this to a minimal example that actually demonstrates the problem in a playground. As you've written it, I had to guess at a bunch of extra code.)

Comment: Actually I didn't post the implementation about my loginResponse (LoginResponse), because I didn't realise that cause the problem. I thought the problem is with my loginRequest.

Comment: BTW thank you for your help, it's working, but honestly I don't know why yet :) I don't understand why I need to pass that "returning" variable to my function, because it looks like I never use it anywhere. But if I comment it out, the code stop working. Could you please give me some hint, where can I find some documentation about this?

Comment: It's used to fill in the type value of `Response`. Type parameters (in `<>`) are very much like value parameters (in `()`). They just need to be passed at compile-time rather than at run time. When I say `func f<T>(returning: T.Type) -> T`, then the `T` passed as `returning` must match the `T` that is actually returned by the function. See `JSONDecoder().decode(T.Type, from: Data)` for the most famous example of this pattern.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out.